# where does oozie stores the captured output values of the Java action (or) any action

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am using the capture-output option for my Java Action. The values I am using in the downstream actions. Which is working fine.
When I do -rerun of the oozie job also framework is fetching the values, without running the Java action again.

I would like to know where does this values stored?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oozie's java action stores captured output/exported properties in a property file defined by Hadoop Job attribute: oozie.action.output.properties at runtime. When  action completed, the data is then serialized to Oozie's backend data store - Mysql or in-memory db, in table - oozie.WF_ACTIONS, column - data.

The data here is then visible to other actions referring to this java action's output.

Comment: Is this file created for each workflow or a common file for all concurrent running workflows?

Comment: I tried to get `System.getProperty("oozie.action.output.properties")` from the machine where Oozie is installed. But got null.

Comment: I got issue - **Output data exceeds its limit [2048]**. I want to check this file to ensure I am not setting irrelevent things.

Comment: It should be on the data node where workflow is running, not on oozie server.

Comment: actually I am using sandbox for HDP 2.3. So everything is running on single machine.

Comment: By the way thanks for replying on an year old answer...:)

Comment: Hi Dev,....."I got issue - Output data exceeds its limit [2048]". How did you solve this issue. I have already set it to 80000 ;)